# Use SSL for JDBC Pool Connection to Oracle Database from Java Application Server

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc, payara

I'm currently trying to implement a SSL connection from the jdbc-pool of our java application server to our Oracle database.

We're using Payara (based on glassfish) as our application server. On there I created a JDBC-connection pool that offers a connection to the database. The goal ist to encrypt this connection.
The used ojdbc driver version is 11-21.1.0.0.

Sadly I only found guides on how to encrypt payara JDBC-pool connections to postgres or mysql databases, not to oracle ones.
The only thing I found was that apparently the pool has to talk to port 2484 on the database ([link](https://www.oracle.com/middleware/technologies/weblogic/configure-use-jdbcdriverssl.html#Setup_WebLogic_to_use_JDBCTHIN_with_SSL)).

Does anyone have any experience with how to solve this problem?
What parameters, aside from port, do I have to set in the advanced properties of the jdbc-pool?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the [JDBC Developer's guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/connection-and-security.html#GUID-DC65B877-2223-40C5-8685-B608D9D2BDC2) for security information?
Check out [www.oracle.com/jdbc](http://www.oracle.com/jdbc) for other resources.